# Base URL in asp.net changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

All working file until I redirect my page to

http://localhost:56180/WebSite2/List/WatchList.aspx
Note: Watchlist.aspx is in folder list.

It is navigated successfully. But after navigating to watchlist.aspx, when I navigate to:
http://localhost:56180/WebSite2/SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx

It automatically adds the List in the URL and said pagenot found.
http://localhost:56180/WebSite2/List/SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx

Note: SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx is located at the base url i.e website2/SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx. Not in the list folder

.aspx code given below:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx">Inititate SRF</a> </li>
<li><a href="List/WatchList.aspx">WatchList</a></li>
<li><a href="List/ApprovalList.aspx">ApprovalList</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's how HTML and URLs work. The base address is *ALWAYS* related to the address of the current page

Comment: Where is `SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx` located exactly?

Comment: at the base url. That is website2/SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx is located in `/website2` folder, add `/website2` in the `href` attribute as below

```
<li><a href="/website2/SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx">Inititate SRF</a> </li>
```

Comment: not working. HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.
It is in the website2 folder.

Comment: Yeah this won't work because it won't have the "WebSite2" folder then.

Comment: @waleedansari I've updated my answer, please try again.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. It will work for now, but I imagine `website2` won't be there in production.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `ResolveClientUrl`

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("SRF-GeneralInfo.aspx")  %>">Inititate SRF</a> </li>
            <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("List/WatchList.aspx")  %>">WatchList</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("List/ApprovalList.aspx")  %>">ApprovalList</a></li>
        </ul>
```